# How to extract hocr file from PDF?

Tags: pdf

I'm creating an OCR-ed PDF through `tesseract`:

```
tesseract input.tif out pdf
```

But I also need the `hocr` and `txt` files.
Recent versions of `tesseract` [already solved this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/commit/270214e667efc4465f48880b4282dd2b934025b5) but because it requires compiling both `leptonica` and `tesseract`, I'm not entirely comfortable with it.

I can use `pdftotext` to extract the text file but I can't seem to find a way to extract `hocr` from the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply run the following command to create both pdf and hocr at the same time.

```
tesseract input.tif out pdf hocr
```